# code works fine locally but when deployed to heroku get "error: (-215:Assertion failed) !image.empty()"

Tags: python, opencv, heroku

In python I am deploying little basic [camera streaming](http://www.chioka.in/python-live-video-streaming-example/) Heroku flask app(full code [here](https://github.com/mauro125/CNT4713). Locally, the code works as expected I am able to see my webcam when I run the code on my computer, when I deploy to Heroku I get this error

> error: (-215:Assertion failed) !image.empty()

running heroku logs --tail command this is what I get [in the logs](https://pastebin.com/7Mjt3cKe)
mainly this error

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:877: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !image.empty() in function 'imencode'

app code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, Response
from camera import VideoCamera
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
    def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        password = request.form['password']
        if password == 'testing':
            return render_template('stream_static.html')
        else:
            return render_template('index.html', message='wrong or empty password')

@app.route('/static', methods=['POST'])
def play():
    return render_template('static.html')

@app.route('/stream', methods=['POST'])
def stream():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

camera.py code:

```
import cv2

class VideoCamera(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        success, image = self.video.read()
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

searching error code online people say to check that its not empty, it's not since the program works as it should(camera streams ok on browser) locally right or is it trying to access the "camera" on the heroku server. If I use this [code](http://www.chioka.in/python-live-video-streaming-example/) the heroku deployed app displays video properly. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: server doesn't have local camera - and server can't access your camera because it is impossible.

Comment: when you run on local computer then it has access only to local camera. When you run code on server then it has access only to camera connected directly to server. But server doesn't have camera. And server can't have access to your local camera. Only web browser may have access to your local camera and send it to server - but it needs web page with JavaScript code which get frames and send to server.

Comment: Ok that's what I figured. I ended up going a different route and am using VLC to stream my camera, thanks for info.